# Entity Framework : issue with defaults

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

Using a DB-first approach, I want to set a default value for a table's column.
I edited the `.edmx` file and in the entity type declaration, I used the following syntax:

```
<Property Name="DOCENTE_ID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" DefaultValue="39735" />
```

When I run model generation, the `DefaultValue` is ignored.

Can someone help me?

Simone

Comment: How do you know the DefaultValue is being ignored? You could also try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Did you try building your solution or manually regenerating the t4 templates after adding that line? When I did what I proposed in the Answer, your change above is the only modification to my edmx file.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Entity Framework are you using? Since it is an EDMX I am going to assume EF 6. I would recommending updating the table in the database to have that default value, and then updating the model from the database. Just right click in the edmx viewer and click Update Model from Database

[image]

If you want to update the edmx, open the diagram and right click the column you want to set and click on Properties

[image]

There you can set the Default Value

[image]

Comment: I use EF 5 and I'm in need to modify the edmx manually. Thanks.